# The dinbrief class with hyperlinks (hyperref) in the address field fails

Tags: hyperref, color, dinbrief

The following minimal example fails to compile, unless one removes the `\href` link from the address field. How can one have links in the address field of a `dinbrief` letter?

```
\documentclass{dinbrief}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=gray,urlcolor=gray}
\newcommand{\mailto}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\address{
  From me\\
  \href{https://google.com/}{my website}
}

\begin{letter}{ To you }
\opening{Dear you,}
\closing{Best regards,}
Text
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

This is an extract from the error log, which does not help me to oncover a fix:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@linkurl ...tionraw >>}\relax \Hy@colorlink 
                                                  \@urlcolor #1\Hy@xspace@en...

\@hyper@readexternallink ...se \hyper@hash #2\fi }
                                                  \fi \fi \fi \fi 
\href@split ...2#$3\\$4->\hyper@@link {$1}{$2}{$4}
                                                  \endgroup 
\@fromaddress ...{https://google.com/}{my website}
                                                   
\ka@db@tsfromaddress ...raggedright \@fromaddress 
                                                  \vss }\nointerlineskip \fi 
\ka@db@placefromaddress ...t{\ka@db@tsfromaddress 
                                                  \vss }\nointerlineskip 
\opening ...} \fi \fi \fi \ka@db@placefromaddress 
                                                  \ka@db@placewindowtics \ka...
l.16 \opening{Dear you,}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! This works for me if I add `\usepackage{xcolor}` to the preamble (before `hyperref`).

Comment: It fails with the exact same error when using the package `xcolor`.

Comment: `\noexpand\href{https://google.com/}{my website}` should work, but I recommend not to use dinbrief anymore. It is not compatible with a current latex and you can get more errors which can't be corrected.

Comment: `\noexpand` lets the document compile but instead of rendering a link it shows both arguments to `\href`.
@UlrikeFischer : What do you recommend instead of `dinbrief`?

Comment: @tuvalu yes sorry, I was a bit to in a hurry. Well it won't work: dinbrief  is not compatible with the new latex hooks, it destroys the begindocument hook, and so all the code hyperref stores there is lost, including the commands to setup the color links.  You find here a number of letter packages https://ctan.org/topic/letter. I have a home made package but if I had to use something external I would probably use scrletter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that dinbrief overwrites core commands and so destroys the LaTeX hooks. If you do e.g. this with a current LaTeX

```
\documentclass{dinbrief}

\AtBeginDocument{\newcommand\blub{Hallo!}}
\begin{document}
\blub
\end{document}
```

then you get an undefined control sequence error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 \blub
```

With other classes, e.g. `article` it would compile fine.

hyperref executes various code in the begindocument hook, and as there are lost link commands no longer work properly.

This is something that can't be corrected externally and it will bite you with other packages too. So unless dinbrief is updated (which is unprobable, we tried to contact the author) it is recommended to use something else to write letters.

Answer (score 1):

This hack worked for me to compile old dinbrief documents (add before `\begin{document}`):

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/document/begin}{
  \begingroup
    \def\@bd@hook{\UseOneTimeHook{begindocument}}
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@preamblecmds\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@bd@hook\@preamblecmds}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

In my case I had to use the `pdfpagelabels=false` hyperref option... (this might be fixable), but this was not needed for the example here:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=gray,urlcolor=gray}
\newcommand{\mailto}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/document/begin}{
  \begingroup
    \def\@bd@hook{\UseOneTimeHook{begindocument}}
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@preamblecmds\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@bd@hook\@preamblecmds}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\address{
  From me\\
  \href{https://google.com/}{my website}
}

\begin{letter}{ To you }
\opening{Dear you,}
\closing{Best regards,}
Text
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

(Note that I also had to add `xcolor`, otherwise `urlcolor=gray` fails.)

Comment: Where in the document do you place this? When I placed it in the preamble (both before and after `hyperref`), the OP's example still didn't compile for me :( perhaps you could edit your question to include a completely compilable document?

Comment: Sorry, my original solution had some problems, esp. when compiling twice (.aux file present).