# Undefined control sequence with dinbrief and pst-barcode

Tags: pst-barcode, dinbrief

minimal example:

```
\documentclass{dinbrief}

\RequirePackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
This is a test.

\end{document}
```

running xelatex from texlive 2021 results in

```
>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-barcode/pst-barcode.tex
`PST-barcode' v0.18, 2017/08/22 (tb,hv)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginnote/marginnote.sty)))
(./input.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ->\special {color push \current@color 
                                                 }\aftergroup \reset@color 
\@outputpage ...t {\vfil \color@hbox \normalcolor 
                                                  \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@theh...

\@opcol ...lumn \@outputdblcol \else \@outputpage 
                                                  \fi \global \@mparbottom \...
<output> ...specialoutput \else \@makecol \@opcol 
                                                  \@startcolumn \@whilesw \i...

\newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M 
                                                  
\enddocument ->\@checkend {document} \newpage 
                                              \begingroup \if@filesw \ifnum ...

\end  ...ook {env/#1/end}}\csname end#1\endcsname 
                                                  \@checkend {#1}\expandafte...
l.8 \end{document}
```

same example works without pst-barcode or when using article instead of dinbrief. any ideas?

Comment: dinbrief doesn't work with a current latex. It redefines \document and so breaks all the begin document hooks. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593321/2388

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. is there something like a plugin replacement for dinbrief? a fork or something different that behaves similar?

Comment: not that I know, but the internet is large.

Comment: @AlexanderStecker: Are you just interested in creating some barcode as part of your document? I'd suggest using something like [`standalone`](//ctan.org/pkg/standalone) to create the barcode in a stand alone document (output is a PDF). Then include that as an image (via `\includegraphics`) in your [`dinbrief`](//ctan.org/pkg/dinbrief) manuscript.

Comment: @Werner: yes, thats the intended use. but we are talking about an open source software, with heavily modified tex files in every installation. i'd rather not have to rewrite all those files. we try to identify the documents which need a barcode and maybe use a different document class in that case (actually, most of them are not a dinbrief at heart. it's more about copy and paste...), and for those that have to use dinbrief, i'll try your suggestion. thank you very much!