# Incompatibility between dinbrief and pdfpages?

Tags: errors, pdfpages, dinbrief

The combination of class dinbrief and package pdfpages is not compiling for me. Here's the MWE (well, minimum non-working example in this case):

```
\documentclass[]{dinbrief}
\usepackage[demo]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
Text here
\includepdf[pages=1]{somePdfFile}
\end{document}
```

And this is the resulting .log after running pdflatex on the .tex file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.5.17)  17 MAY 2023 01:40
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./anschreiben_mimimal.tex
(anschreiben_mimimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-11>
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/dinbrief\dinbrief.cls

Document Class/Style 'dinbrief' - Version 1.73 
University of Karlsruhe - 2000/03/02 12:49:21 

*** dinbrief: Running in LaTeX 2e mode!
*** dinbrief: NFSS 2!
Document Class: dinbrief 2000/03/02 LaTeX2e class
\ka@db@tmpdima=\dimen140
\ka@db@tmpdimb=\dimen141
\@mainlbl=\write3
\GZA=\dimen142
\ltf@headheight=\dimen143
\lts@headheight=\dimen144
\ltf@headsep=\dimen145
\lts@headsep=\dimen146
\ltf@textheight=\dimen147
\lts@textheight=\dimen148
\ka@db@txtlmarg=\dimen149
\addrhpos=\dimen150
\addrvpos=\dimen151
\addrwd=\dimen152
\addrht=\dimen153
\addroffset=\dimen154
\ka@db@addrhoffs=\dimen155
\backaddrht=\dimen156
\reflinevpos=\dimen157
\ufldmarkvpos=\dimen158
\lfldmarkvpos=\dimen159
\perfmarkvpos=\dimen160
\ka@db@foldmarkhoffs=\dimen161
\ka@db@perfmarkhoffs=\dimen162
\ka@db@foldmarklen=\dimen163
\ka@db@perfmarklen=\dimen164
\bottomtextvpos=\dimen165
\ka@db@headup=\dimen166
\ka@db@vfuzz=\dimen167
\ka@db@stdskip=\dimen168
\ka@db@fieldwd=\dimen169
\ka@db@fldskip=\dimen170
\ka@db@shfldwd=\dimen171
\ka@db@indadr=\dimen172
\dlabelheight=\dimen173
\dlabeltopmargin=\dimen174
\dlabelwidth=\dimen175
\clabelnumber=\count185
\cspare=\count186
\c@lt@state=\count187
\c@letter=\count188
\labelcount=\count189
\c@labelgen=\count190
\yearcnt=\count191
\@betr=\box51
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/dinbrief\dinbrief.cfg))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pdfpages\pdfpages.sty
Package: pdfpages 2022/12/19 v0.5x Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count192
\calc@Bcount=\count193
\calc@Adimen=\dimen176
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen177
\calc@Askip=\skip48
\calc@Bskip=\skip49
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count194
\calc@Cskip=\skip50
)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/eso-pic\eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2023/05/03 v3.0c eso-pic (RN)
\ESO@tempdima=\dimen178
\ESO@tempdimb=\dimen179

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
) (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\mathcolor.ltx
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)) (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cf
g
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen180
\Gin@req@width=\dimen181
)
\AM@pagewidth=\dimen182
\AM@pageheight=\dimen183
\AM@fboxrule=\dimen184
 (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pdfpages\ppnull.def
File: ppnull.def 2022/12/19 v0.5x Pdfpages dummy driver (AM)

Package pdfpages Warning: I will use a dummy \includepdf command
(pdfpages)                which will insert empty pages instead of the actual
(pdfpages)                PDF file because we are running in `demo' mode.

)
\pdfpages@includegraphics@status=\count195
\AM@pagebox=\box52
\AM@global@opts=\toks17
\AM@pagecnt=\count196
\AM@toc@title=\toks18
\AM@lof@heading=\toks19
\c@AM@survey=\count197
\AM@templatesizebox=\box53
) (anschreiben_mimimal.aux)
\openout1 = `anschreiben_mimimal.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.


Package pdfpages Warning: I cannot determine the number of pages of the
(pdfpages)                included document, because we are running in
(pdfpages)                `demo' mode. 
(pdfpages)                You can use the option `lastpage' to give me a hint.

! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                                  }\aftergroup \reset@color 
\@outputpage ...t {\vfil \color@hbox \normalcolor 
                                                  \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@theh...

\@opcol ...te@singlecol@structures@@ \@outputpage 
                                                  \fi \global \@mparbottom \...
<output> ...specialoutput \else \@makecol \@opcol 
                                                  \@startcolumn \@whilesw \i...

\newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M 
                                                  
\AM@output@i ...ean {AM@endoflist}{false}\newpage 
                                                  \whiledo {\not \boolean {A...

\\includepdf ...ndafter {\the \AM@global@opts ,#1}
                                                  \fi \AM@CheckAtEnd \endgro...
l.9 \includepdf[pages=1]{somePdfFile}
                                     
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                                  }\aftergroup \reset@color 
\@outputpage ...footskip \color@hbox \normalcolor 
                                                  \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@thef...

\@opcol ...te@singlecol@structures@@ \@outputpage 
                                                  \fi \global \@mparbottom \...
<output> ...specialoutput \else \@makecol \@opcol 
                                                  \@startcolumn \@whilesw \i...

\newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M 
                                                  
\AM@output@i ...ean {AM@endoflist}{false}\newpage 
                                                  \whiledo {\not \boolean {A...

\\includepdf ...ndafter {\the \AM@global@opts ,#1}
                                                  \fi \AM@CheckAtEnd \endgro...
l.9 \includepdf[pages=1]{somePdfFile}
                                     
? 
[1

{C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                                  }\aftergroup \reset@color 
\@outputpage ...t {\vfil \color@hbox \normalcolor 
                                                  \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@theh...

\@opcol ...te@singlecol@structures@@ \@outputpage 
                                                  \fi \global \@mparbottom \...
<output> ...specialoutput \else \@makecol \@opcol 
                                                  \@startcolumn \@whilesw \i...

\newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M 
                                                  
\AM@output@i ...e \@firstcolumnfalse \fi \newpage 
                                                  \ifthenelse {\boolean {AM@...

\\includepdf ...ndafter {\the \AM@global@opts ,#1}
                                                  \fi \AM@CheckAtEnd \endgro...
l.9 \includepdf[pages=1]{somePdfFile}
                                     
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                                  }\aftergroup \reset@color 
\@outputpage ...footskip \color@hbox \normalcolor 
                                                  \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@thef...

\@opcol ...te@singlecol@structures@@ \@outputpage 
                                                  \fi \global \@mparbottom \...
<output> ...specialoutput \else \@makecol \@opcol 
                                                  \@startcolumn \@whilesw \i...

\newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M 
                                                  
\AM@output@i ...e \@firstcolumnfalse \fi \newpage 
                                                  \ifthenelse {\boolean {AM@...

\\includepdf ...ndafter {\the \AM@global@opts ,#1}
                                                  \fi \AM@CheckAtEnd \endgro...
l.9 \includepdf[pages=1]{somePdfFile}
                                     
? 
[2] ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2239 strings out of 476360
 34229 string characters out of 5788497
 1850993 words of memory out of 5000000
 22688 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512287 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,8n,76p,238b,258s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on anschreiben_mimimal.pdf (2 pages, 12959 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I believe this can be traced back to the packages directly. This is a new install of Miktex on Windows. I was using the exact same combination of class and package on an older computer with an older Miktex install, so presumably something became incompatible in the meantime. Do you know how to solve this incompatibility?

Comment: See the comments under [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593846/208544). Probably shouldn't use dinbrief with new documents. Perhaps [g-brief](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/g-brief) could be a replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dinbrief` is incompatible with all LaTeX versions from 2020/10/01. (IMHO it wasn't fully compatible even earlier, but from that LaTeX release it breaks the `\begin{document}` code of LaTeX and so very often causes errors.) So you should not use it any longer.

As a workaround *for old letters you still need to compile*, you could try a LaTeX version rollback using package `latexrelease`:

```
\RequirePackage[2020/03/02]{latexrelease}
\documentclass[]{dinbrief}
\usepackage[demo]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
Text here
\includepdf[pages=1]{somePdfFile}
\end{document}
```

But note, that this would not work for all documents, because the current releases of some other packages depend on current LaTeX releases and therefore would fail with the rollback. In such a case you would have additional effort to make it run again.

There are several alternatives for (not only) German letters that work with an up-to-date LaTeX release, e.g., [`g-brief`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/g-brief), [`scrlttr2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlttr2), [`scrletter`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrletter), [`akletter`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/akletter) etc.