Dinbrief, texlive 2021 and date
we use since 2007 the dinbrief style to write german letters.
Normally one could date the letters with \date{DD.MM.YY} to set a special date.
Since we now have TexLive 2021.20210325 with Opensuse Leap 15.5, this is not possible anymore, everytime only the date of today is written. In the .log-Files there is no warning thrown. Has anybody an idea?

Welcome! Can you provide an example with just enough code to be a complete document we can compile to reproduce the problem?

dinbrief is not compatible with a current latex. Better use something else write letter. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593321/2388

I can't reproduce the issue. With the example letter in the manual (https://texdoc.org/serve/dinbrief/0 page 5) with TeX Live 2021, 2022 and 2023 adding \date works fine and produces the supplied date in the pdf.

While compiling the minimal example i found the solution.
To use dinbrief with Texlive 2021, we need to use the command
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}.
After some changes in the central latex documents in the last weeks,
the \RequirePackage-command ended up after the beginning command \documentclass[11pt]{dinbrief}.
As I fiddled with the minimal code, I found out that using \RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease} before \documentclass{dinbrief}
the command \date{DD.MM.YY} worked again.
But as U. Fischer mentioned, dinbrief is really outdated, so we will try g-brief soon.
