How do I use combine with newtxtext?
It seems the combine package does not play nice with newtxtext.  Here's a minimal failing example (incorporating the usual "Extra \endgroup" workaround):
\documentclass[12pt]{combine}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\makeatletter\let\document\c@ladocument\begingroup\makeatother
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}

Some slightly abridged console output from pdflatex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./proposal.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/combine/combine.cls
Document Class: combine 2010/07/10 v0.7a collection of documents 
(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)))
(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxtext.sty
`newtxtext' v1.744, 2024/04/01 Text macros taking advantage of TeXGyre Termes a
nd its extensions (msharpe)
⋮
(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty)) (./proposal.aux
) (/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/ot1minntx.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                                  }\aftergroup \reset@color 
l.6 \end{document}
                  
?

A similar error message is reported in Automatic provision of title making through class file but the accepted answer, which advises adding \AtBeginDocument{\let\default@color\current@color}, does not solve my issue.
Is there a solution that I can apply directly in the master document, rather than separately in each document that I want to \import?

don't use combine with current latex.

Fair enough; if it's that dangerous, then I can hack together something with subfiles instead. I wanted something that could combine multiple independent documents, each with its own \title and \author.  subfiles isn't designed for that but can be tricked into doing so.

I said that because that was the response a previous question about using combine got from one of the current latex developers. when one of them says that, it generally means something is already broken and likely to stay that way. subfiles was the suggested alternative, but there is also standalone. (I know people think it is just for making graphics, but it can actually do rather more than that.) I'd use titling to enable multiple titles/authors. It's pretty old code, but works well with standalone latex is changing a lot & combine's maintainer is just not interested.

combine redefines \document and that breaks all document hooks. So e.g. \AtBeginDocument{\show\blub} does nothing at all. The situation is similar to dinbrief: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593321/2388.
